# Mirror all packages from a Nuget repository

Tags: nuget, artifactory, mirror

I have two questions about mirroring Nuget packages using the `nuget mirror` command ([reference](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#mirror-command)).

We are migrating our internal Nuget repository to Artifactory and for the time being I need to have all the packages (and all their versions) from the original nuget repo mirrored to Artifactory.

**First**, does `nuget mirror` take into account packages that are already present at the destination? Because so far no matter what I do, the package is always re-uploaded with every call, even though it is already there. Setting up a job responsible for mirroring all the packages would be pretty costly if it always re-uploaded all of them.

**Second**, is it possible to tell the command to mirror *all* packages? The documentation states I have to either specify a package ID or a file containing the IDs, but I want to mirror them all.

Related, is it possible to tell the command to mirror all versions of a package? Because if a version is not speficied, only the latest one gets mirrored.

Thanks

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet2/blob/dev/src/CommandLine.ServerExtensions/PackageMirrorer.cs) (line 103), it looks like it's supposed to upload the package only if it doesn't exist in the repo already.

Comment: Second: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Haacked/NuGet/blob/861741bd780225a542c73a1d0904dd33b33a7a3d/src/CommandLine.ServerExtensions/MirrorCommand.cs) again tells us that indeed, the command only supports either a package id or a file containing the package ids. Two possible ways to do what you're after is either to produce a file with all the ids or to fork the source for the mirror and implement a variant pulling all packages from the remote repo yourself.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will consult with the rest of the team what is a viable course of action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments - `nuget mirror` can only mirror a single package/version. In order to mirror all packages, you need to make a script that scrapes the package info from the Nuget server and then mirror them one-by-one.